# How to move keyboard up over many textFields inside UiView

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3

I have the following in the ViewController:

a) a long viewScroller ( 1000 Height)

b) This long viewScroller contain a UIView Which is 1000 Height, called it 1stView

c) In this 1st UIView (1000 Height), it contain another UiView ( called it 2ndView)

d) in this 2ndUIView( the size: W300x H290) , it contains 5 textFields.

The problems:

1) How to I move the 5 textFields above the Keyboard when user click any one of the textFields to enter data?

for problem (v1) as below

2) below code for problem (V2).
   When click outside ( 2ndView or in 2ndView ) the keyboard wont go away.

3) current codition without any implementation for moving the Keyboard up, the 1st TextField can be seen above the keyboard when user click the textField and need to scroll to see the others. Will AppStore approve this User experience?

```
class ItemViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField4: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField5: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField1.delegate = self
        textField2.delegate = self
        textField3.delegate = self
    textField4.delegate = self
        textField5.delegate = self

    }

    //-(V1)- handle textfield

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

          textField.resignFirstResponder()
          return true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UItextField) {

    }


    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    }


   //-(V2) Called when the user click on the view (outside the UITextField).

   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        self.view.endEditing(true)
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView` from https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding. Will solve all your scrolling problems and will hide the keyboard too. When selecting a text field way down it will automatically scroll it in view.

Comment: see https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager